# How to replace last digit in a line with the same digit and a fullstop?

Tags: regex

I am looking for a RegExp to find and replace all instances of last digits in a line with the same digit and a full stop in Memsource, which seems to be not working properly.

Example:

Pic. 12-1
Pic. 12-2
Pic. 12-3

To:
Pic. 12-1.
Pic. 12-2.
Pic. 12-3.

I've chosen them by `\d$` but when I try to replace them with a `\.`, `.$` etc. it seems not to be working properly. Any advice would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: `(\d)$` -> `\1.` (or `$1.`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @WiktorStribiżew stated in the comments, you can use `(\d)$` as the pattern to match and `\1.` as the string to replace it with.  A quick breakdown of how this works is:

- `(\d)` Matches any digit and captures it in group 1
- `$` Matches the end of the line
- `\1.` Replaces the the matched string with the first capture group followed by a period

Resulting in `(\d)$` -> `\1.`

However, is it necessary to even match the digit? Would the following substitution suffice `$` -> `.`? This would simply add the `.` to the end of each line. The only issue would be that it would not discriminate whether or not the line ends with a digit.

If it must end with a digit to receive a period, you can also avoid using capture groups by using a positive look-behind. In this case the pattern to match would be `(?<=\d)$` and the replacement pattern would be `.`.

- `(?<=\d)` Is a positive look-behind that checks if the there is a digit before the current character without consuming any characters.
- `(?<=\d)$` Checks to make sure the character at the end of the line is a digit with consuming that character (i.e. that character will not be replaced).

The resulting replacement would then be `(?<=\d)$` -> `.` which would add a period to each line that ends with a digit without the need for capture groups.

Further reading:

- [Grouping and Capturing](https://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html)
- [Lookahead and Lookbehind](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)